# insert to database with checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a way to upload a value to SQL using a checkbox but no luck

this is my code:

```
/////////////////////////// FOR RXTRA ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$sql = "SELECT ext_id,ext_price,ext_name,ext_description FROM tbl_extra ORDER by ext_id ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
$number = mysql_num_rows($result);
$i = 0;
while ($number > $i) {
  $ID = mysql_result($result,$i,"ext_id");
  $NA= mysql_result($result,$i,"ext_name");
  $PR= mysql_result($result,$i,"ext_price");
  $DES= mysql_result($result,$i,"ext_description");

  //this part chack if the value is "0" and show with "tooltip" the value\/

  if ( $PR == 0 ) {
    print '<a href="#" class="tooltip2">'.$NA.'<span>' .' free '.'</span></a>!';
  } else {
    print '<a href="#" class="tooltip2">'. $NA .'<span>' .' add '.'  '. $PR .' $ '. '</span></a>!';
}
print "<input style='width: 30px; height: 15px;' type='checkbox'  name='extra[]' value='$NA'></td>\n";

//this java calculate the value add to extra ant outpot the total extra that pass to sql table
print "<input type='hidden' name='item_name'/>";
print "<input type='hidden' name='amount'/>";


print "<input style='width: 30px; height: 15px;' type='checkbox' onClick='ReadForm (this.form, false);' value='+$PR'></td>\n";
$i++;
}
?>
</div></div>
<?
} else {
}
?>
<!----->
<div class="item_add_cart">
<span class="title">total extra $</span>
<div class="content">
<?
print "<input style='color:#000;font-size:13px;' size='7' name='tot' type='text'/>";
?>
</div></div>
<!----->
```

my problem is that I have two table's one is the total price and one is the names I try to insert all value with one checkbox and it's not working

If I create 2 checkboxes and click on them then the value uploads ok
but I need only one checkbox that sends value from `$NA` to Table ext_name and total price from name='tot' to ext_price table

Comment: @all, please people, if someone posts code, do not fix the code in the question, other than layout. Fix it in an answer.

Comment: @all, Otherwise the question the OP asked will be killed beyond all recognition.

Comment: Too many problems with this code. (1) The last `} else { }` will result in a syntax error (or maybe you have an open `if` block which starts before the snippet posted here); (2) Hidden inputs for `item_name` and `amount` should be arrays: `item_name[]` and `amount[]`; (3) You are not assigning any value to these hidden inputs. (4) You need to include the javascript `ReadForm` function here, we cannot see what it does. (5) This snippet is the part that creates the form, you are not showing the backend submit handler which is responsible for inserting the values into db.

Comment: @Majid why don't you point those out in an answer, how is the OP supposed to learn from his mistakes, if he/she can't even see what was wrong with it in the first place because someone edited the errors out. Especially so when the complaint is `its not working`

Comment: @John, the trick you used (making the answer community wiki) did not occur to me, I had the same concern ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the above code doesn't work, @Majid Fouladpour suggests the following code instead.

```
/////////////////////////// FOR RXTRA ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$sql = "SELECT ext_id,ext_price,ext_name,ext_description FROM tbl_extra ORDER by ext_id ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
$number = mysql_num_rows($result);
$i = 0;
while ($number > > $i) {
$ID = mysql_result($result,$i,"ext_id");
$NA= mysql_result($result,$i,"ext_name");
$PR= mysql_result($result,$i,"ext_price");
$DES= mysql_result($result,$i,"ext_description");

//this part chack if the value is "0" and show with "tooltip" the value\/

if ( $PR == 0 ) {
    print ''.$NA.'' <a href="#" class="tooltip2">'.$NA.'<span>' .' free '.'!';
.'</span></a>!';
} else {
    print ''. <a href="#" class="tooltip2">'. $NA .'' '<span>' .' add '.'  '. $PR .' $ '. '!';
</span></a>!';
}
print "\n";<input style='width: 30px; height: 15px;' type='checkbox'  name='extra[]' value='$NA'></td>\n";

//this java calculate the value add to extra ant outpot the total extra that pass to sql table
print "";
<input type='hidden' name='item_name'/>";
print "";<input type='hidden' name='amount'/>";


print "\n";
<input style='width: 30px; height: 15px;' type='checkbox' onClick='ReadForm (this.form, false);' value='+$PR'></td>\n";
$i++;
}
?>





total >
</div></div>
<?
} else {
}
?>
<!----->
<div class="item_add_cart">
<span class="title">total extra $</span>
<div class="content";
>
<?
print "<input style='color:#000;font-size:13px;' size='7' name='tot' type='text'/>";
?>



>
</div></div>
<!----->
```

*(I've made this answer community wiki so the rep doesn't go to me)*